# User Registration Form: Empty Email

Tags: craft3, emails, user-profile, registration

I am using Craft 3 with the default Craft 3 user registration form. Whenever I register I get an empty email. If I go to the cms and manually click on 'send activation email' I get a correct activation email like it should be. What could be causing this?

There are no errors in the error logs, the test mail is working just fine, all the other emails like the forgot password email is also working fine.

Comment: So you get an activation email, but there's literally no body in it?  If you go to Settings->Email->System Messages in the Control Panel, do you have copy in the "When someone creates an account:" section?

Comment: Right, and in the Email settings I have the default system email template. And when creating a user using the CMS it works properly

Comment: Something I just found out that is also worth noting: Any changes I make to the 'active your account' template are not getting saved, even if I add just one space it doesn't get saved and when I reload the page the template is replaced by the default template.

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed that might be hooking into the email sending/saving process?

Comment: No, I don't have any plugins like that. I think this might be a bug. When I created a new admin account I was actually able to edit and save the default email template. What I did was, I removed {{user.friendlyName}} from the template and tried again. After this everything worked properly again. Then I put back the user.friendlyName and saved it (using my newly created admin account) and tried registering using the frontend form again. This time it also worked. I have no clue what is going on. I still can't edit the email template using my regular admin.. but at least the email is not empty